# Dynamically Adding Information to Fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

The issue I'm having is that I don't know how to get a pointer to a layout within a fragment.  It's obvious that to get a layout pointer in Java you would do something like this:

```
 LinearLayout llTemp = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llTemp)
```

Something along those lines.

Now what I'm doing is grabbing information from a server in the main class and load a fragment within the same class.  I would like to populate the fragment with the information loaded from the outer class.  Is there any way to do this?  I would have just grabbed the layout from within the fragment and do it that way but I cannot make a reference to it as it's in the fragment.

I'm sure this is a common problem but I couldn't find anything on it specifically like this.

Thanks in advance,
Cheers,
Jake

To Answer the comment:

```
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_frag, container, false);
 mainLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ll_MainFrag);
 return view;
```

This is what is in my onCreateView.

Okay, just to add how I'm instantiating the Fragment:

```
 private int MAIN = 1;
 FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
 fragments[MAIN] = new MainFragment();

 FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
 transaction.commit();

 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.flMain, fragments[MAIN]).commit();
```

From here I would like to be able to do something like:

```
 fragments[MAIN].createTextView();
```

Comment: What does the onCreateView in your fragment look like?

Comment: What is the "main class" (as you call it)? If it's an `Activity` then it can call public methods in any `Fragment` it maintains.

Comment: Yeah, so I have an Activity that gets started then it creates a fragment within the Activity.  I then get the information from a server within my Activity and I would like to create a list essentially within the fragment using that information.

Comment: @JakeAlsemgeest : As I said, the `Activity` can call methods in the `Fragment`. Just create a public method, pass the data grabbed from the server to it and have the `Fragment` manage its own list.

Comment: As you can see in the code I provided to answer the other comment I have a LinearLayout which is set to the main Layout within the fragments XML.  When I tried to make it just add a TextView from the Fragment class it Failed.

Comment: Sorry, but also, how can I call the method from my Activity class?  Obviously you make a public method in the fragment class but I'm instantiating the fragment in an array, so how do I go about calling it?  I have it something like: fragments[1] = new MainFrag();  Then I can't do fragments[1].createTextView();

Comment: @JakeAlsemgeest : **"Then I can't do fragments[1].createTextView();"** - Well no, array indexes are zero-based. As long as the `createTextView();` method is public, however, you could do `fragments[0].createTextView();`

Comment: I said fragments[1] only cause it's the second fragment in the array haha.  Either way, I tried fragments[1].createTextView(); and it didn't work.  I mean I cannot actually see the createTextView(); from my activity class when I do fragments[1]. usually using Eclipse you can do the ctrl+space and see a list of methods that are available and it is not one of them.  Yes I did make it public.

Comment: If you're defining your array using the base `Fragment` type such as `Fragment[] fragments = new Fragment[x]` then when you try to access a public method in one of the fragment array elements, you'll need to cast it to the actual type. Example `((MainFragment)fragments[MAIN]).createTextView();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a Fragment, create public methods to set data:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private TextView text1;
    private TextView text2;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View layout = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.simple_list_item_2,container,false);

        text1 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        text2 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text2);

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void setData(String t1, String t2){
        text1.setText(t1);
        text2.setText(t2);
    }
}
```

When adding a fragment in parent activity, give it a unique tag:

```
 MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(f,"my_fragment").commit();
```

Later, you can search the fragment from parent activity and call some methods on it:

```
 MyFragment frg = (MyFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("my_fragment");
 if(frg != null){
    frg.setData("abc","def");
 }
```

Also, if fragment was added from a layout, you can find the fragment by its `id`.